# Can't convert utf8 buffer into ISO8859_1 buffer without data loss

Tags: node.js, iconv

As an example, I'm trying to convert the following utf8 string into ISO8859_1

String = `Plœmeurl’`

The String's hex representation: `50 6c c5 93 6d 65 75 72 6c e2 80 99 20`

After iconv-lite conversion to ISO8859_1:

`50 6c 3f 6d 65 75 72 6c 3f 20`

The hex value once inserted in my ISO8859_1 database looks like this:
[image]

Code:

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
iconv.encode(Buffer.from(`Plœmeurl’ `, 'utf8'), "ISO-8859-1")
```

Am I doing something silly ?

Comment: Well the characters `œ` and `’` do not exist in ISO8859_1. Both are listed as missing characters on the wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Languages_with_incomplete_coverage, and "this scheme does not provide for oriented (6- or 9-shaped) single or double quotation marks"

Comment: Oh it had to be a silly mistake. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out I had to convert to windows-1252.

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense indeed. Glad to have been of any help.